# Azure Devops Pipeline resource trigger error

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a `C# solution` with mutiple executable projects and I want to do a pipeline to build exe files and dependencies and another pipeline to generate multiple installers using Advanced Installer.

In the build pipeline I'm using the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task at the end.

I have seen that I have two options to achieve this.
Using classic release pipelines (it works properly).
Another option seems to use yml pipeline triggered by the first pipeline. I have done it following docs but i'm getting an error configuring the trigger.

*Configuring the trigger failed edit and save the pipeline again*

```
trigger: none

pool:
   name: Default
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals 'SelfHostedAgent'

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'projectCi'
    source: '\Folder\Project-CI' 
    trigger: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. The problem was that the default branch doesn't have the pipeline defined.
I have to set default branch via UI.
Menu > Triggers > YAML > Get Sources > Default Branch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your YAML Sample, you are defining the project name at source field of Pipeline Resource.

The format has some issue.  You need to define the project name at the **Project** field.

You can use the following format:

```
trigger: none

pool:
   name: Default
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals 'SelfHostedAgent'

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'projectCi'
    project: 'Projectname'
    source: 'Project-CI' 
    trigger: true
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Define a pipelines resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource)

Comment: It's not the project name, sorry for confussion. Both pipelines are in the same project.
It seems that in Default branch was not defined the pipeline. You have to point default branch in repo settings in UI. now it seems to work with my yml code. I have added the answer to question